# Expansion of solids on heating

Tags: thermodynamics

I read that when we heat a solid, it expands! Based on circumstances it can expand in area, length and volume! My question is , that do they expand to a certain extent or keep on expanding, if we continuously provide them a great amount of heat!

Thanks

Comment: A solid will keep expanding until it melts or sublimes. Is this all you were asking, or are you trying to get at more detail about what expansion is and why it happens?

Comment: Often there are temperature regimes where solids shrink as the temperature increases. For metals these are mainly at low temperatures. Polymers tend to have negative coefficients of thermal expansion even at room temperature.

Comment: [True](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBXL93984cQ), though I suspect this isn't what the OP had in mind.